# I'm trying to match a bolt and a nut

Tags: hardware

If a 5/16 inch nut is too small, and a 7/16 inch nut is too big, what size nut do I need?

Comment: Dang, now what is that number between 5 and 7?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is trivial.

Comment: @FredricShope  It might not be trivial to the OP.

Comment: @FredricShope  Matching a bolt and nut does take quite a bit of knowledge.  Is it standard or metric size, is it fine or coarse thread,  what class is the thread, and what strength grade is needed for the bolt and nut.

Comment: It's a good question, and the answer is, you really don't know.  The best bet is to take it to a REAL hardware store that has all the bins of bolts and nuts.  Why? Because it might be one of several thread pitches of 3/8", but it also might be one of several metric thread pitches of 8mm or 10mm.  They may have thread pitch gages on a chain, those help. The correct nut will roll down easily, don't force anything or you'll damage the threads and then you'll never know what fits easy (because nothing will).

Answer (score 5):

I would try a 6/16 inch nut, always know as a 3/8 inch nut. If that doesn't work, go to your home store and sit down in the nut section and try them all until you find one that fits. Along with different diameters, there are different thread sizes.

Comment: most hardware stores have a template with a selection of nuts and bolts attached to it  ... similar to https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/FYJ/Y3UO/H3NN9JMA/FYJY3UOH3NN9JMA.jpg?auto=webp&frame=1

Comment: @jsotola  Someone keeps ripping that off at the HD I go to...LOL

Comment: It would need to be a REAL hardware store, the kind with the slide-out bins with loose hardware in it, where it's semi-honor-system and you write down the price on little bags they provide.   Trying to do it in the bleeping big-box store, with their comically limited selection and everything in little plastic bags - forget it, I've tried.  Also, OP may have metric.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica "you write down the price on little bags they provide" I have one of those in my town :-). For those unfamiliar with traditional British ironmongers (hardware store) [this may help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CmaLgxLDE0).

Comment: @Graham yeah, the difference is, a proper American hardware store is dusty, has 100 nooks and crannies and improvised mezzanines and alcoves, and some stocked items going back to the steam age because the store has been there for 90 years.  A British one has been there for 900 years LOL.

Answer (score 5):

A 6mm bolt takes a 10mm nut, which is about 3/8".

Most of the world has left the folly of Imperial measure behind. Don't discount the possibility that you have a metric nut in hand.

Comment: I think you meant drive/wrench size when talking about M6 taking a M10 nut.

Comment: I didn't use the term "M10" in my answer, but yes, that was my meaning.

Comment: An M6 screw takes an M6 nut. The nut requires a 10 mm across-flats wrench/socket. The screw and nut need to have the same pitch - coarse, fine, extra fine.